# Class 'Appkernel' not found when updating to Symfony 3.0

Tags: php, symfony

I tried updating my code and structure to Symfony 3.0. Doing the usual composer update, I've got this error when composer execute post-update-cmd :

```
    Fatal error: Class 'AppKernel' not found in C:\wamp\www\tharmofos\bin\console on line 20

Call Stack:
    0.0002     235192   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\tharmofos\bin\console:0


Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\wamp\www\tharmofos\vendor\jms\security-extra-bundle\Tests\Functiona
l/../../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\tharmofos\vendor\jms\security-extra-bundle\Tests\
Functional\AppKernel.php on line 5

Call Stack:
    0.0002     235192   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\tharmofos\bin\console:0
    0.0249    1144472   2. Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler::handleFatalError() C:\wamp\www\tharmofos\vendor\symfony\sym
fony\src\Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler.php:0
    0.0263    1162640   3. Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler->handleException() C:\wamp\www\tharmofos\vendor\symfony\symf
ony\src\Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler.php:600
    0.0292    1260456   4. Symfony\Component\Debug\FatalErrorHandler\ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandler->handleError() C:\wamp\w
ww\tharmofos\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler.php:530
    0.0292    1262144   5. Symfony\Component\Debug\FatalErrorHandler\ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandler->getClassCandidates() C:
\wamp\www\tharmofos\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Debug\FatalErrorHandler\ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandler.php:
62
    2.5849    1595232   6. Symfony\Component\Debug\FatalErrorHandler\ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandler->findClassInPath() C:\wa
mp\www\tharmofos\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Debug\FatalErrorHandler\ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandler.php:118

    2.6446    1600616   7. Symfony\Component\Debug\FatalErrorHandler\ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandler->convertFileToClass() C:
\wamp\www\tharmofos\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Debug\FatalErrorHandler\ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandler.php:
143
    2.6453    1642120   8. require_once('C:\wamp\www\tharmofos\vendor\jms\security-extra-bundle\Tests\Functional\AppKernel.p
hp') C:\wamp\www\tharmofos\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Debug\FatalErrorHandler\ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandl
er.php:188

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated wit
h an exception


  [RuntimeException]
  An error occurred when executing the ""cache:clear --no-warmup"" command:
  Fatal error: Class 'AppKernel' not found in C:\wamp\www\tharmofos\bin\console on line 20
  Call Stack:
      0.0002     235192   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\tharmofos\bin\console:0
  Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\wamp\www\tharmofos\vendor\jms\security-extra-bundle\Tests\Func
  tional/../../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\tharmofos\vendor\jms\security-extra-bun
  dle\Tests\Functional\AppKernel.php on line 5
  Call Stack:
      0.0002     235192   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\tharmofos\bin\console:0
      0.0249    1144472   2. Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler::handleFatalError() C:\wamp\www\tharmofos\vendor\symfon
  y\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler.php:0
      0.0263    1162640   3. Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler->handleException() C:\wamp\www\tharmofos\vendor\symfony
  \symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler.php:600
      0.0292    1260456   4. Symfony\Component\Debug\FatalErrorHandler\ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandler->handleError() C:\w
  amp\www\tharmofos\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler.php:530
      0.0292    1262144   5. Symfony\Component\Debug\FatalErrorHandler\ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandler->getClassCandidates
  () C:\wamp\www\tharmofos\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Debug\FatalErrorHandler\ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHa
  ndler.php:62
      2.5849    1595232   6. Symfony\Component\Debug\FatalErrorHandler\ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandler->findClassInPath()
  C:\wamp\www\tharmofos\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Debug\FatalErrorHandler\ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandl
  er.php:118
      2.6446    1600616   7. Symfony\Component\Debug\FatalErrorHandler\ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandler->convertFileToClass
  () C:\wamp\www\tharmofos\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Debug\FatalErrorHandler\ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHa
  ndler.php:143
      2.6453    1642120   8. require_once('C:\wamp\www\tharmofos\vendor\jms\security-extra-bundle\Tests\Functional\AppKer
  nel.php') C:\wamp\www\tharmofos\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Debug\FatalErrorHandler\ClassNotFoundFatal
  ErrorHandler.php:188
```

As of now, I tried to delete the vendor folder and did a composer install but I keep getting this error.
When I try accessing my website, I get this error :

```
Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle' not found in C:\wamp\www\tharmofos\app\AppKernel.php on line 11
```

I think it's a problem with the structure update.

Do you have any clue ?

Comment: 1. make sure you change all of this: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/UPGRADE-3.0.md

2. post here your composer.json or make sure the versions of dependencies look like here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/composer.json (for example sensio/framework-extra-bundle is there version ^3.0.2 ...)

Comment: What have you done exactly to "update your code and structure for Symfony3"? AppKernel and AppCache were added to the autoloader, haven you done this change?

Comment: I already fixed all deprecation notices in my code before updating.
My composer.json is looking just like the one from the example.

To update code and structure, I've fixed all deprecation notices I could in my code. Then, I tried to find a suitable version of each bundle I use in my app. And I updated to Symfony 3.0. 
Concerning the structure, I've created var and bin directories and moved all the files required to these. I copied Appkernel's code from Symfony standard but I didn't know I had to autoload it and I don't know how to do it. Can you help me with this please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony3: Fatal error: Class 'AppKernel' not found in .\bin\console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36286998/symfony3-fatal-error-class-appkernel-not-found-in-bin-console)

Answer (score 2):

I found out how to get rid of this error by autoloading AppKernel.php in composer.json : https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/issues/868

Answer (score 0):

If it can help, I often forget to upgrade a Symfony Standard file (like app/console, web/app.php, web/app_dev.php, app/config/routing_dev.yml...) when upgrading a project to 3.0.

It leads to this error.